# Outgoing call events in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outgoing call status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099782/outgoing-call-status)

my application need outgoing call events. for example, The call is connected to destination device? or the destination device is switched of? or not reachable..How can I get these events in android? are there any API's in android?

Thanks
shiv

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and the different Call States

Comment: I found some methods in TelephonyManager for In_comming_call not for out_going_call. can you suggest the correct API's to find the destination device accept the call or rejected or not-reachable

Comment: you basically have to watch for broadcasted ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED Intents. You can dump(log) the state, using the EXTRA_STATE key presented in the Intent Extras, to see what values are there when you're dialing(out), ringing(inc), hangup(inc), answering(inc), when the user on the other side answers etc...